# Open a text file from server on the Client-side using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file, fileapi

No matter how much I look this up all I get is the w3C File API which focuses on local files for the client.

What I'm trying to do is I have a server. I'm trying to use client-side javascript to grab the server hosted text file, a.txt, and display it to the innerDOM of an html page. My server directory look like this:

- index.html
- read.js
- text files

  - a.txt

All I want to have happen is for, on the client side, the javascript read.js running in the index.html on onload to display the contents of a.txt. I figure that since a.txt will never be large, leaving it to the client is fine.
But I can't figure out how to do this and the W3C File API isn't offering me answers.

If I had to guess, somehow making sure index.html loads a.txt and then grabbing that via the file API might be the way to go but I'm not sure how to do that.

And I'll admit it, I'm a bit of a noob. If I'm invalidating browser sandbox or doing something impossible, please tell me. I just thought this would be so simple.

Also, I'd appreciate that if you were going to suggest AJAX, either don't, or explain it like I'm a baby because I really don't know.

Thank you all so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why file API is irrelevant:

> Web applications should have the ability to manipulate as wide as possible a range of user input, including files that a user may wish to upload to a remote server or manipulate inside a rich web application.

From [W3C File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#introduction).

So, File API is intended to be used to allow users to *upload* files from their clients into the server. On the other hand, AJAX is used to allow users to *download* files and other data from the server into their clients. And this is exactly what you need.

Refer to [jQuery's ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this page should help you out with your problem.
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=YhNukIHynD3

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an Ajax call to the file on the server, since the response of the call will typically be the contents of that file.
Using Jquery this can be done by a simple

```
$.ajax({ 'url':'a.txt',
    'success': function(r){
        //display to innerDOM here, using r as the file
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply want to display a txt file on the web page?
Do you know about server side includes?
That would be one possibility if you control the server.
If you really want to do it in javascript, then AJAX would be the way to go.
If it were me at that point I would figure out how to include and use jQuery to help with the ajax bits.
You will simply request the text file via its URL (you can get it to load in the browser right?), and then use jQuery to put that text into some DOM element.